# How to periodically run a task?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, alarmmanager, android-handler

I started building my app to send JSON strings to a server, however it is only sent when I click a button. I would like it to be sent automatically after a time that is specified by the user from a TimeDialog. I was suggested to use AlarmManager or Handler, but I do not know how to implement it with my app. I have provided the line of code that will be executes and sends to my server. Any help or suggestions?

Code used I would like it to be run after specified time:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.saveBtn:

            if (!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
            new HttpAsyncTask().onPostExecute("server_adress"); //was execute but changed!
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Util Timer class to do what you want.

you can see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm) an example.

Try to use it!!!

Comment: for some odd reason, it cannot import ' import java.awt.Toolkit; '

Answer (score 0):

While an alarm manager/handler is often the best way schedule future events on Android, Google suggests using a Sync Adapter when scheduling network calls like your application synching to the server at a given interval. The framework provides a predefined user authentication, background scheduling so that you app does not need to be running to make the call, improved battery performance, and handling the case when there is no network connectivity at the time scheduled. Here's their developer page on [using Synch Adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html).